# How do I calculate the average for multi-axis voting for a specific node?

Tags: 7, rating

I need to calculate average for multi-axis voting for different nods or content types.

For example, I have three different voting axes in node "A" and below them must appear the fourth field with the average.

It will be better if this field has a tag as voting axes have.

I saw solutions using tag "vote" but they used it to average all other multi-axes. So I can not use different multi-axes for each node or each content type.

Comment: For this question to make sense, you should include how you setup voting on the node, which modules you use etc.